# Jolt: Json string literal to json object

Tags: jolt

I am looking for the way to transform JSON string to Json object.

I have a Json
input:

```
{
"item":"{\"currency\":\"USD\",\"content\":\"12\" TV\"}"
}
```

Is there a way to transform the string to json object using Jolt?

expected output:

```
{
"item":{"currency":"USD","content":"12\" TV"}
}
```

Thanks
David